# Redirect port for specific hostname?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, port, hostname

Lets say I have two domains pointing to my IP:

**first.com** and **second.com** pointing to **127.0.0.1**


When someone connects to **first.com:6000** it should go to **127.0.0.1:6000**. But when someone connects to **second.com:6000** I need it to go to **127.0.0.1:6001**.


What's the best way to achieve this? I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Can you please better clarify what you are looking to achieve?  Is the communication via http(s) or via some other protocol?  Also are the domain names CNAME DNS records to each other or are they unique IP addresses?

Comment: There's only one IP address.

Comment: You're 50% there... there's one other question you forgot to clarify on:
Is the communication via http(s) or via some other protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The domain name gets resolved to an IP address by the connecting client, and the IP communication to the server just contains a request for the port on the IP address that it resolved to. You will have to change your software configuration to find another solution. You either need to programatically make a different request in the first place or have the answering server do some work in the background or perhaps your API can prompt for the domain as part of your chat with the port.

Comment: Actually, *if* this is indeed http traffic, a solution could be set up fairly easily using Apache VirtualHosts and mod_proxy.

Comment: It's not http traffic.

Comment: There is more than "A" (address) records on dns servers. For example, in this case "SRV" could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

For some protocols you could use SRV dns records: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a multiplexer for TCP connections. Probably you can use HAProxy (http://www.haproxy.org/) to do what you want, but there are more options. HAProxy is not limited to HTTP connections. For example, I know someone who has used it for SMTP connections. The idea is a follows. You define a HAProxy frontend running on port 6000 that has two rules for dispatching traffic:

```
frontend frontend_name
  bind *:6000

  acl first_host hdr(host) -i first.com
  acl second_host hdr(host) -i second.com

  use_backend first_backend if first_host
  use_backend second_backend if second_host
```

Then you define two backends for each host. You will need three separate ports for frontend and two backends. I have not personally tested it, but the syntax should be more or less OK.

Edit: This will work only for HTTP/HTTPS connections. However, if your protocol includes the server name in a request it might be possible to extract the server name from the request with req.payload function.

Comment: haproxy can only work with pattern if used protocol including fqdn in requests. Protocol is still not known here. So it may work only in some cases.

Comment: Good catch! Indeed, the acl matching by the fqdn will require HTTP/HTTPS connections. I've updated my answer about the limitations.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a web-server like `apache` or `nginx` running on port 6000. This web-server can then re-route your requests to desired port as your pre-defined rules.

Comment: it is not http traffic as user76231 told. So apache or nginx it will not work in his case.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that comment. Yes, you are right. This will not work for non-http traffic.